# SSJS Triggered Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I'm trying to send a TSD from a CloudPage using SSJS.

```
    var tsd = TriggeredSend.Init("EmailAddressChanges_ConfirmationTS");
    EmailUpdate.TriggerStatus = tsd.Send(email,{Customer:custNo,ContactID:contactId,NewEmailAddress:newEmail});
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Unable to queue Triggered Send request. There are no valid subscribers.
```

I'm confused on the email parameter...shouldn't I need the SubscriberKey?

Comment: Here's the documentation I'm going off of: https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/triggered_send_server_side_javascript_functions/send/

Comment: Have you verified that the email variable has a valid email address? (not unsubscribed/correct formatting, etc..)

Comment: Yes, I'm also tracking to a log DE and all the variable data is correct. I'm still unclear as to why it only accepts email address??? What if 2 different SubKeys have the same email address?

Comment: I agree. I have not used this function before, I usually prefer to use the API call.  If the email is valid, then according to the documents, it SHOULD be working - perhaps try putting it to SFMC global support as well.

Comment: I have an open ticket. I don't expect much from Support unfortunately, that's why I came here. :-)

Comment: I did some exploration on it as well and have had no luck.  Once you get an answer from support, please post it here so anyone else that comes into this issue is able to see the solution.

Comment: So the error I was getting was data related and not actually being caused by the SSJS send function. That being said, the SSJS send function does not allow for Subscriber Key to be passed. So the email parameter adds the same value for Subscriber Key and Email Address to the TSD Data Extension. Fortunately we are not adding the Subscribers to All Subs, we just need this for a simple notification email.

Answer (score 1):

Typically this happens if you are not passing all the required fields in the Triggered Send data extension. In addition to Email and Subscriber key are you also requiring any other email send meta data like first name or something?

Answer (score 0):

This error is also generated when you attempt to send multiple triggered sends to the same subscriber and the "Update Subscribers" checkbox is not selected in the Triggered Send definition.